# Design in jFrame form in netbeans not loading

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

[image: this is a screen capture of the window]

the design part in netbeans jframe form is just loading, not allowing me to edit anything or create any new jFrame form. i tried to uninstall netbeans and reinstall it, but nothing changed. i also tried to turn off my antivirus (McAfee) due to the fact that it gave me other problems in my computer but still nothing changed.  i ran this program yesterday and it was just fine. last thing i remember doing after that is trying to connect it to a database and added the connector to the libraries. i also added a java mail library today.

Comment: *"i ran this program yesterday and it was just fine. last thing i remember doing after that is trying to connect it to a database and added the connector to the libraries."* 1) Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()` 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Don't add screenshots of the bloody IDE. They're as useful as a screen door on a submarine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to

- uninstall netbeans,
- then delete (or move) the `netbeans.conf` file and
- install netbeans again.

Depending on which version of Netbeans(and Operating System) you are using this file will be in different places. Please take a look to this [FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf) to have a better idea.